# How do I print an array using jQuery from xml data?

Tags: jquery, html, xml, arrays, onload

I'm just trying to print a jQuery array from an XML file.  Here's my code.  I'm trying to print stockList as you can see from the html code.  Also, did I do the onBodyLoad correctly?

HTML:

```
    <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
      <div id="stockList"></div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div id="stockInfo"></div>
   </body>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "stocks.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (onBodyLoad) {
            var stocklist = new Array();
            var stockinfo = new Array();
            $(onBodyLoad).find('Stock').each(function () {
                var company = $(this).find('Company').text();
                var market = $(this).find('Market').text();
                var sector = $(this).find('Sector').text();
                var price = $(this).find('Price').text();
                $(onBodyLoad).find('YearRange').each(function () {
                    var low = $(this).find('Low').text();
                    var high = $(this).find('High').text();
                });
                $(onBodyLoad).find('Dividend').each(function () {
                    var amount = $(this).find('Amount').text();
                    var yieldx = $(this).find('Yield').text();
                    var frequency = $(this).find('Frequency').text();
                });
                stocklist = $(company);
                $('#stockList').append('<div><p>' + stocklist + '</p></div');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

XML:

```
<Stock symbol="GOOG">
    <Company>Google</Company>
    <Market>NASDAQ</Market>
    <Sector>Software</Sector>
    <Price>$487.80</Price>
    <YearRange>
        <Low>$331.55</Low>
        <High>$488.50</High>
    </YearRange>
    <Dividend available="false"/>
</Stock>
<Stock symbol="BA">
    <Company>Boeing Company</Company>
    <Market>NYSE</Market>
    <Sector>Aerospace</Sector>
    <Price>$79.05</Price>
    <YearRange>
        <Low>$63.70</Low>
        <High>$89.58</High>
    </YearRange>
    <Dividend available="true">
        <Amount>$1.20</Amount>
        <Yield>$1.50</Yield>
        <Frequency>QTR</Frequency>
    </Dividend>
</Stock>
```

Desired output: 
Google 
Boeing Company

Comment: Did you... try running it? It looks reasonable, except that the two `.each()` calls won't do anything (all they do is set variables which are local to the callback functions), and the line `stocklist = $(company);` is weird because `company` contains the `text()` of the `Company` element, but it will get evaluated as a selector string. And as Bhushan mentioned, `onload="onBodyLoad()"` is ineffective and unnecessary.

Comment: <body onload="onBodyLoad()">: I cant find any function named onBodyLoad!!

Comment: Plz post the xml code and your desired output

Comment: I added some xml code and the desired output for the given code

Comment: Also isn't the success function named onBodyLoad?

Comment: Why do you think that, swerley? "onBodyLoad" has no special significance in either pure javascript or jQuery. It appears to be used in Phonegap.

Comment: ready function doesnt have a name. It will be automatically called when the document is loaded

Comment: And why do you assign the other fields of xml to local variables, if you need only the company field?

Comment: I need to do more, if I can get the beginning I should be able to figure the rest out.

Comment: onbodyload here means just the xml file (as you have set it as the parameter for success function)

Comment: Ah, okay, that's understandable.  The onbodyload is a secondary thing for me.  I need to get the array to print and I'd be ecstatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To collect the company names, sort them, and print them:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "stocks.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xmlData) {
            var companyNames = [];
            $(xmlData).find('Stock').each(function () {
                var company = $(this).find('Company').text();
                companyNames.push(company);
            });
            companyNames.sort();
            $.each(companyNames, function (index, name) {
                $('#stockList').append('<div><p>' + name + '</p></div>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I need to figure out how to store the elements in an array because I need them sorted.  Some of the stuff that seems unuseful just ignore, it's because I haven't hit that part of the project yet.  I'm currently just trying to store the companies in an array, sort them (which I know how to do), and print them.

Comment: For some reason I'm still getting no output.  Everything you have looks legit and makes sense to me.  Maybe I have something wrong with my set up, I'll look into it.  Once it's working I'll give you the check!

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this:

```
<body>
      <div id="stockList"></div>

   </body>
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "stocks.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
         success: function(xml){
         var newArray = [];
            $(xml).find('Stock').each(function () {
                var company = $(this).find('Company').text();

               newArray.push(company );


            });

           newArray.sort();

            $(companyNames).each( function (index, name) {
            $('#stockList').append('<div><p>' + name + '</p></div>');
        });

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I need it in an array because it needs to be alphabetically sorted.  I know how to alphabetically sort if the array prints.

Comment: @swerley you should probably have mentioned that in the question